# HtmlPurifier add unsupported stylesheet for one tag

Tags: htmlpurifier

I use HTMLPurifier 4.6.0 to filter HTML. My HTML have this line:

```
<pre style="overflow-x: scroll; word-wrap: normal; white-space: pre;">
```

After submitting it has been truncated:

```
<pre style="white-space: pre;">
```

I want allow ONLY for <pre> style "overflow-x:scroll" and "word-wrap:normal".

I found this page http://htmlpurifier.org/docs/enduser-customize.html and tried:

```
    $config->set('HTML.DefinitionID', 'enduser-customize.html');
    $config->set('HTML.DefinitionRev', 1);
    $config->set('Cache.DefinitionImpl', null); // TODO: remove this later!
    if ($def = $config->maybeGetRawHTMLDefinition()) {
        $def->addAttribute('pre', 'style', 'overflow-x');
    }
```

I have problems with setting [addAttribute](http://htmlpurifier.org/doxygen/html/classHTMLPurifier__HTMLDefinition.html#acb4dd65983a9b5e39af3a331a54d9d00)(). Can anybody help me here? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution with this settings:

```
$css = $config->getCSSDefinition();
$css->info['overflow-x'] = new HTMLPurifier_AttrDef_Enum(array('scroll'));
$css->info['word-wrap'] = new HTMLPurifier_AttrDef_Enum(array('normal'));
```